# Python How to fix this

Tags: python, list

```
 list1 =[1,2,3]
 list2 = [4,5,6]
 list1.append(list2)
 list2.pop()
 print(list1)
```

Display [1, 2, 3, [4, 5]]

the value in list1 disappear

Answer (score 2):

You need to make a copy of `list2` and append that instead.

For example:

```
 list1 =[1,2,3]
 list2 = [4,5,6]
 list1.append(list2[:])
 list2.pop()
 print(list1)
```

Adding the `[:]` at the end of `list2` in the `append` statement makes a copy of the list.

So your output will be:

```
[1, 2, 3, [4, 5, 6]]
```

`list2` will still have it's last value removed, but it will have no effect on `list1`

Answer (score 1):

Python list pop() removes and returns the last value from the List or the given index value.

that's why the last index of the last list will be deleted